# How to handle user registration over django_rest_framework based API

Tags: django, api, authentication, serialization, django-rest-framework

How do I handle user registration over and API using django_rest_framework? Specifically, how would I set up a password field in the UserSerializer

```
class NewUserSerializer(serializer.Serializers):
    first_name = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=30)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=30)
    username = serlializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=30)
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=True)
    password = ???

    def restore_object(self, attrs, instance=None):
        if instance:
            instance.username = attrs.get('username', instance.username)
            instance.first_name = attrs.get('first_name', instance.first_name)
            instance.last_name = attrs.get('last_name', instance.last_name)
            instance.email = attrs.get('email', instance.email)
# Would the instance.password field be necessary? 
            instance.password = attrs.get('password', instance.password)
        else:
            return User(**attrs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a CharField for password. And you even dont need a restore_object at all. You can just do it like this, define fields like you do and then :

```
   serializer = NewUserSerializer(data=request.DATA)
   if serializer.is_valid():         
      email = serializer.object["email"] 
      password = serializer.object["password"]
      # do the stuff you want here
```

Comment: Why would I not want to add a restore_object method? What if a user decides to change their email address or password?

Comment: I just was mean if it was on for registration this logic can go out of serializer. anyway, if you want it to return actual User object instance and your concern is a password you should just use CharField for password and in the restore_object use a set_password method, not a direct assign.